# Generate a movie with ffmpeg from a changing still image url?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to create a movie/stream with ffmpeg from a HTTP url that points to an image. This image gets updated 1 time per second.

I already know how to convert from MPEG-4 to flv for example using the ffmpeg command line, but now I need to start from this still image that gets updated. I would like ffmpeg to 'GET' the url 1 time per second for example.

regards,

Wim

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? - unfortunately, the answer doesn't seem to work on newer versions of ffmpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command line option needed is `-loop_input`. I am currenly using this command line to do it:

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -analyzeduration 0 -r 3 -i http://ipaddress/current.jpg -an -re -copyts -f flv output.flv
```

The `-loop_input` instructs ffmpeg to read the jpg on the given URL at the input frame rate (3 fps in this example). The `-analyzeduration 0` will give a quicker startup and show the first frame of your movie faster. The output can be anything, in the example here, it is a flash movie, but it can be anything ffmpeg supports.

Comment: How does ffmpeg know when to stop polling the input source?

Comment: It does not know. It will keeping polling until you stop ffmpeg

Comment: `-loop_input` is deprecated in favor of `-loop`, which unfortunately doesn't re-read HTTP URL's. (Even if the returned image has `Cache-Control:none`). Even trying `-pattern_type sequence` and adding `?dummy=%d` to the URL fails, as the sequence numbering is incompatilbe with URL's as well.

Comment: Unrecognized option 'loop_input' :(