# Loop input on a http url with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I loop input on a http url with ffmpeg?
The http url jpg is dynamically changing so every time I call the http url its a new image.

I have already tried these commands below.

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i http://127.0.0.1/api/gfx/frame.jpg -codec mpeg4 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/stream`

`ffmpeg -r 1 -filter_complex loop=loop=-1:size=100:start=0 -i http://127.0.0.1/api/gfx/frame.jpg -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/stream`

This comment makes it seems like there is no support or work around.

*-loop_input is deprecated in favor of -loop, which unfortunately doesn't re-read HTTP URL's. (Even if the returned image has Cache-Control:none). Even trying -pattern_type sequence and adding ?dummy=%d to the URL fails, as the sequence numbering is incompatilbe with URL's as well. – MSalters Jul 18"
[Generate a movie with ffmpeg from a changing still image url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026699/generate-a-movie-with-ffmpeg-from-a-changing-still-image-url)*

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can just use loop 1 on images

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i http://127.0.0.1/api/gfx/frame.jpg -codec mpeg4 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/stream
```